# UITextView with Very Long Text

Tags: swift, string, uitextview

I have an UITextView in a UIScrollView.
The textView's text have **3000 characters**.

When I set font size to 20.0, it's fine.

But when I increased the font size to 40.0, letters are disappearing. However, the textView is still selectable.

```
//text:String have 3000 characters.
textView.text = text
textView.font = textView.font?.fontWithSize(40)
```

Here's the images.

[image: textView with font size 20]
[image: textView with font size 40]

When the text has 6000 chars, letters are gone at font size 30.

Does UITextView have such a limit? Or is it a bug?

Thanks for your answers (Xcode 7.3.1 & iOS 9.3)

Comment: do you have to change lineHeight property or it changes automatically?

Comment: It changes automatically. But I tried to change it manually. lineHeight is increased, but still letters are disappeared.

Comment: i have the same problem, does anyone have a solution?